# The best way or code to create counter hits using session, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, session, counter

Below, I have pasted the code that I found the best way to do counter hits using PHP, MySQL and session. But I want to find out is there any other way to do this process? Or this way is only the way to do counter hits on session? I want to learn other ways as well, if you guys know it then it will be really helpful.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once"db.inc.php";
$webpage=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

$sql= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counter (
id int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
webpage varchar(90) NOT NULL,
visitors int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1"; 

mysql_query($sql);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM counter WHERE webpage='$webpage'");
$num_rows= mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows== 0){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO counter (id, webpage, visitors)
VALUES ('','$webpage','1')");

}else{

if (!isset($_SESSION['webpage'])){$_SESSION['webpage']= 0;
mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET visitors=visitors+'1' WHERE webpage='$webpage'");}}
?>

<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> Just a test </title>

</head>
<body> 

<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM counter WHERE webpage='$webpage'");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$n=$row['visitors'];
$l=9-strlen($n);
$z=substr('',0,$l);
$c="Counter: ".$z.$n;

echo "<div class='counter'>".$c."</div>";

mysql_close();
//session_unset();
//session_destroy();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Offtopic here. There is a different stackexchange site for codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The *"best way"* depends entirely on "you". There is no "best way"; however there are methods that stand at being more efficient than another. You just need to test out different ways and see which one(s) come out on top. (*There's more than one way to skin that Waskiwee Wabbit*)

Comment: Obligatory Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You have two massive, gaping security holes in there. Please tell me this isn't in production yet. (also, post this on codereview since it's asking for best practises)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no use of session while recording page hit :

```
if ($num_rows== 0){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO counter (id, webpage, visitors) VALUES ('','$webpage','1')");

}else{

// if (!isset($_SESSION['webpage'])){$_SESSION['webpage']= 0; /* you can remove this line */
mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET visitors=visitors+'1' WHERE webpage='$webpage'");}
```

And while viewing the count, remove some line, as those are useless...

```
$n=$row['visitors'];
//$l=9-strlen($n); /* you can remove this line */
//$z=substr('',0,$l); /* you can remove this line */
//$c="Counter: ".$z.$n; /* you can remove this line */
$c="Counter: ".$n;  /* removed $z  */

echo "<div class='counter'>".$c."</div>";
```

Hope this will help..